# ASPxTextBox KeyDown event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, devexpress

I have ASPxTextbox and I'm trying to prevent users to typing letters. So I have my control code:

```
<dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="phone" Text="" runat="server" MaxLength="18" Width="100px>
  <ClientSideEvents Validation="Validation" KeyDown = "SkipLetters"/>
  <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithText" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" ValidateOnLeave="true" />
                                                                                        </dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```

and JavaScript for `SkipLetters`:

```
function SkipLetters(s, e) {
 
        if (e.htmlEvent.keyCode <= 90 && e.htmlEvent.keyCode >= 65) {
            e.htmlEvent.returnValue = false;
        } 
   
}
```

I know when the letters are typing in but actually I don't know how to prevent it :) I've tried to `var content = s.GetText()` as first call in `SkipLetters` but it's too late, content is changed. So should I in if statement `GetText`, find letters and erase them or is there any possibility to prevent adding them to textbox content?

Comment: As far as I know it is the only once option do you have. If you want to be on the save side, add the events 'keyUp' and 'change' with the same functionality. Background is, you can catch the paste action with the mouse (right mouse button and then the paste action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. "Use the force trn!" if someone needs:

```
<dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="visiblePhoneNumber" Text="+48" runat="server" MaxLength="18"
     Width="100px">
     <ClientSideEvents Validation="PhoneNumberValidation" KeyPress = "CheckKey" />
     <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithText" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" ValidateOnLeave="true" />
     <ValidationSettings>
         <RegularExpression ValidationExpression = "[0-9\s\-\+\(\)]{9,18}" />
     </ValidationSettings>
 </dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```

JavaScripts:

```
function CheckKey(s, e) {
    var key = ASPxClientUtils.GetKeyCode(e.htmlEvent);
    var char = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (e.htmlEvent.shiftKey) {
        if (!IsAvailableChar(char))
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEvent(e.htmlEvent);
    } else
    if (!(IsAvailableChar(char) || IsAvailableKey(key))) ASPxClientUtils.PreventEvent(e.htmlEvent);

    return;
}

function IsAvailableChar(char) {
    var AvailableChars = "0123456789+- ()";
    return AvailableChars.indexOf(char) != -1;
}

function IsAvailableKey(key) {

    switch (key) {
    case 8: //backspace
        return true;
        break;
    case 189: //minus
        return true;
        break;
    case 46: //delete
        return true;
        break;
    case 37: //left arrow
        return true;
        break;
    case 39: //right arrow
        return true;
        break;
    case 16: //shift
        return true;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
        break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ASPxSpinEdit for this purpose.  It was specially designed to allow the end-user to input only numbers.

Comment: thx for your help - but does ASPxSpinEdit allow user to put signs like +, -, (, ) ? because pepople type phone numbers using so many formats - for example (71) 333-444-111 or 321 123 321. I really care that they don't need to think bout the format number, my app will parse them later.